# delete from mysql - angular nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js

I need help to perform a delete and update with angular.
In nodejs is ok, test with restApi in firefox

Part of the angular controller for delete operation

```
$scope.deleteCustomer = function (index) {

           var alert = confirm("Do you really want to delete the task?");

           if (alert == true) {
               $http.post('/customers/',  {
                   customer: $scope.names[index]
               })
                   .then(function success(e) {

                       $scope.errors = [];

                       $scope.names.splice(index, 1);

                   }, function error(e) {
                       $scope.errors = e.data.errors;
                   });
           }
       };
```

Html code:

```
                          <td>{{customer.id}}</td>   
                          <td>{{customer.name}}</td>



                          <td>
                                <button ng-click="updateCustomer($index)"  class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Edit</button>
                                <button ng-click="deleteCustomer($index)" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</button>
                            </td>
                     </tr>
```

With this code I can delete a row but if I refresh the page the row is not deleted from database.

Comment: I literally searched for "perform a delete and update with angular" and got some answers. If you want help here you need to show that you have run into something not explained in another SO question or on the web.

Comment: Sorry, but I have nothing found. I cant pass the id. The error is DELETE http://localhost:3000/customers/ 404 (Not Found)

Comment: 404 means that resource is not found. You need to work from the known to the unknown. Is this service even listening at localhost:3000? Is the resource /customers actually present? Does this instance even support DELETE? Does this resource? These are pretty fundamental questions that only you can answer.

Comment: @j82 Did you write the backend service that will perform the DELETE on the database ?